# How to notify progress for a YouTube video upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, youtube-api, progress-bar

I am working on a ASP.NET Web API with Angularjs for client side programming. My application users will be uploading/watching videos in my application. I want to upload these videos to YouTube (using YouTube API for server side).

For now I have completed the uploading part, but I am not sure how to show a process bar on client side browser with real indication of the progress of the video being uploaded. I can capture the progress on the server side as I am using the following code for uploading:

```
VideosResource.InsertMediaUpload insertRequest = youtube.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet, status", fileStream, "video/*");
insertRequest.ProgressChanged += insertRequest_ProgressChanged;
insertRequest.ResponseReceived += insertRequest_ResponseReceived;

insertRequest.Upload();
```

Here I can capture the `ProgressChanged` event to see the progress, but how can I notify my end user (browser) these progress updates?

Comment: the mighty c# Task! check out this for reference. http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress

Comment: I am already capturing the progress in c# code which is my server side code. What I need is to notify this progress to client side (HTML in browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havea lot of ways, here are couple of them:

- **Make AJAX requests** from client side to server **in loop**, and get progress. In this case you need to save progress in `insertRequest_ProgressChanged` into static storage (Static Dictionary of uploads).
- Use [**SirnalR**](http://signalr.net/). This will allows you to make direct updates.

Anyway you need to store progress of your uploading in any storage.

For example you can create static class, something like:

```
public static class UploadingDispatcher
{
    private static Dictionary<Guid, Int32> Uploads = new Dictionary<Guid, Int32>();
    private static object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void Add(Guid id)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            Uploads.Add(id,0);
        }
    }

    public static void Remove(Guid id)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            Uploads.Remove(id);
        }
    }

    public static int GetProgress(Guid id)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (Uploads.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return Uploads[id];
            }
            return 100;
        }
    }

    public static Boolean SetProgress(Guid id, Int32 value)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (Uploads.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                Uploads[id] = value;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Before your code you should create Upload by:

```
Guid uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();
UploadingDispatcher.Add(uploadId);
```

In your `insertRequest_ProgressChanged` method use UploadingDispatcher to update progress:

```
UploadingDispatcher.SetProgress(id);
```

You need to create separate action to get progress, like `GetUploadingProgress`. In this action method you can get progress by calling:

```
UploadingDispatcher.GetProgress(id);
```

To remove Upload from UploadingDispatcher after file is uploaded use:

```
UploadingDispatcher.Remove(id);
```

Comment: Thanks. Which of them is a better choice? Also, where should I save the progress as I am using Web API as back end so there is no user session? Sorry I forgot to mention Web API in question, therefore updating the question too :)

Comment: Looks cool. Shouldn't I consider the ASP.NET SignalR for this purpose? What are the advantages and disadvantages between these two approaches?

Comment: SignalR will allows you to make single continuous request instead if loop of get requests. If it is single place where you want to use SignalR the  I will prefer old way - loop with request, that is easier to implement

Comment: HI,i have seen that you said "Make AJAX requests from client side to server in loop" can u please come with sample code for uploading & showing file progress with ajax. i just do not understand for what reason one should use loop for file upload progress.